# key down not working after inserting new form and command button to go from one form to other

Tags: visual-studio-2017, keydown

After inserting a new form and button to go from one form to other (me.hide and from2.show) key.down event is not working .

Comment: try to add your code for help. without code we can't help you.

Comment: how can  i send you the project?

Comment: upload your project on github or google drive then share link